# jquery stop popup button click generating other clicks

Tags: jquery, click

I have an image map with a click event which places a marker image on it:

```
$('#map').on('click', function(e){
    var pin = $('<div class="pin"></div>');
    $('#map_wrapper').append(pin);
```

then clicking the pin opens a PNotify popup with a text input and a save button, clicking on which appends the entered text to the wrapper:

```
$('#map_wrapper').on('click', '.pin', function(e){
    var id = this.id;
    notice = new PNotify({
        text: form,
        ...
    });
    $('#pin_text_form [name=save]').off('click').on('click', function(e){
        $('#' + id).append('<p class="pin-text hidden">' + $.trim($('#pin_text').val()) + '</p>');
        notice.remove();
```

The problem is that after clicking the form's Save button another pin is added to the map, that is both the popup's click and the map's click are fired.

I tried:

```
$('#pin_text_form [name=save]').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
```

but none of these prevent the main map click from firing.

I also tried taking the button click outside of the map click function, but now the save click still fires the map click AND the notice doesn't get removed anymore.

I also tried:

```
$('#map_wrapper').on('click', 'pin_text_form [name=save]', function(e){
    $('#' + pin_id_clicked).append('<p class="pin-text hidden">' + $.trim($('#pin_text').val()) + '</p>');
    notice.remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
```

no change.

How do I stop a map click after a Save click and remove the notice after the click?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ `Live()` event's can't be stopped according to the docs. Live is depreciated but `on()` replaces this functionality. So i guess it's the same for the 'live' `on()` event.

Comment: Have you written one click event handler inside another? why? and e.prevent etc , which e is it? the pin adding event or saving event? you code has only one e.

Comment: Could you post a properly formatted code? Atleast mention where your methods are starting and closing.

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi, yes, I've got one click event inside the other - is this what's causing the problem? (I missed the 'e' when copying)

Comment: @MarkBaijens, then OP should be getting syntax error for : e.preventDefault(); etc, because there is no e defined. I think OP has written handlers one inside other

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi My bad, mis understood it. The code formatting is pretty bad.

Comment: @linuxoid yes. Dont do that, you are exponentially adding events on the same div. Also e.preventDefault that you have written is preventing the main event because e is the parameter only in the 1st event. Write them seperately.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Thats true.

Comment: I can't take the button click outside because it won't know which pin ID was clicked to open the popup

Comment: Store that id outside the hander. Refer the answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

Do not cascade the event handlers.
And store the id outside the eventHandler to access it.

Looking at your code, it looks like you always have once instance of `save form`, so one pin id `var` should be enough.

```
var currPinId = "";
$('#map_wrapper').on('click', '.pin', function(e){
    currPinId = this.id;
    notice = new PNotify({
        text: form,
        ...
    });]
}); //end of  event handler

$('#pin_text_form [name=save]').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    $('#' + currPinId).append('<p class="pin-text hidden">' + 

    $.trim($('#pin_text').val()) + '</p>');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I tried this but now the button doesn't work AND the map click still fires, and the notice popup doesn't get removed after click

Comment: I added e.preventDefault(); but this didn't help either

Comment: It's probably because of the form being part of the notice which the notice being inside the map click function, so regardless whether it's inside or outside of the map click, clicking the save button is still processed by the map.

Comment: I've moved the notice and button click function completely outside of the main function - still the same behavior with click, although the notice now closed after click. I can't figure out what causes adding a new pin to the map on Save button click. I alerted 'e.target.id' and e.currentTarget.id' - these pop up after clicking the map, nothing happens after clicking the Save button but the pin actually appends...